# Why the inputView of an iPhone app is so wrong on an iPad Air?

Tags: ios, ipad

Last night I was playing with a friend's new iPad Air in the bar. I downloaded [my own app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/minimalist-calculator/id593028402?mt=8) onto his new iPad Air and found a very weird bug.

My calculator app for iPhone looks typically like this:

[image]

The keypad is an `inputView` of `UITextField`.

However, when the app runs on the iPad Air, no matter at 1x or 2x mode, it is like:

[image]

Some of the keys are randomly positioned. I ran the app on my Mini (1st gen) before without such issue. Do you have an idea what cause the keys relocation?

Comment: Have you updated your app to IOS 7?

Comment: @nicael no, not iOS 7

Comment: Your Mini is probably running IOS6, but Air is running IOS7

Comment: @nicael no, my Mini and iPhone 5s are both running iOS 7.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug only shows up when the calculator is started during the iPad is at landscape mode. Fixed by removing excess suppoorted landscape modes from the Info.plist:

[image]